# Why does the alpha value change when I have given it a constant value?

Tags: colors, p5.js

I am using the p5.js Web Editor

```js
        var sketch = function (p) {
          with(p) {

            p.setup = function() {
              createCanvas(400, 400);
              secCanvas = createGraphics(400, 400);
              secCanvas.clear();
              trans = 0;
              drop_size = 10;
              sun_size = 50;
              radius = 10;
            };
        
            p.draw = function() {
              background(3, 182, 252, 1);
              image(secCanvas, 0, 0)
              secCanvas.fill(255, 162, 0, 1)
              secCanvas.ellipse(width/2, 0 + sun_size, sun_size)
              fill(40, trans)
              trans = random(255);
              ellipse(random(mouseX + radius, mouseX - radius), random(mouseY + radius, mouseY - radius), drop_size)
              drop_size = random(50)
            };
            
          }
        };
        
        let node = document.createElement('div');
        window.document.getElementById('p5-container').appendChild(node);
        new p5(sketch, node);
```

```css
    body {
      background-color:#efefef;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
    <div id="p5-container"></div>
```

When I set a discrete value of alpha in secCanvas.fill(). The value appears to be gradually increase(and stops soon), while I gave no such instruction. Why is this happening? This only happens when I put `background(3, 182, 252, 1);` in the draw function but not when I put it in the setup function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each frame is drawn on top of all previous frames, so when you draw a semi-transparent background, you can still see the previous frames underneath it.

Think of it as adding a very thin coat of paint over top what you've already painted. Because the color you're adding is semi-transparent, you can still see what's underneath it. Then during the next frame, you add another layer of paint, and the previous frames get just a little more faint.

They stop becoming more faint because of the way the computer calculates the new color, based on the previous frames and the new semi-transparent background color. Long story short, the color you're drawing is almost 100% transparent, so it's not strong enough to completely hide previous frames.

Comment: I want to use a transparent background, is there a way around this?

Comment: @Dr.danks Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question. You *are* using a transparent background, which is causing the behavior you're seeing. Can you be more specific about exactly what behavior you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the transparent background to have a constant transparency.

Comment: @Dr.danks Your transparent background does have a constant transparency, which is drawn over top of previous frames, which causes them to fade over time. If you want your background to have a constant color, then you might not want to use transparency. If you want to use the transparency as a filter, then I would consider drawing your circles to another graphics, and then drawing the background (or a rectangle) on top of that canvas.